# Display the name of the month in the date

Tags: date, jquery-ui, format

I display a date range in my code, which appears as this: 06-08-2017 - 12-08-2017.
But what I would like to see is this: 06 August - 12 August
I wondered how to do it.

Here is the code I use to display dates:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var startDate;
        var endDate;
        // configure the bootstrap datepicker
        var selectCurrentWeek = function() {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                $('#js-datepicker').find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').addClass('ui-state-active')
            }, 1);
        }

        $('#js-datepicker').datepicker({

            //config default
            altField: "#datepicker",
            closeText: 'Fermer',
            prevText: 'Précédent',
            nextText: 'Suivant',
            currentText: 'Aujourd\'hui',
            monthNames: ['Janvier', 'Février', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juillet', 'Août', 'Septembre', 'Octobre', 'Novembre', 'Décembre'],
            monthNamesShort: ['Janv.', 'Févr.', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juil.', 'Août', 'Sept.', 'Oct.', 'Nov.', 'Déc.'],
            dayNames: ['Dimanche', 'Lundi', 'Mardi', 'Mercredi', 'Jeudi', 'Vendredi', 'Samedi'],
            dayNamesShort: ['Dim.', 'Lun.', 'Mar.', 'Mer.', 'Jeu.', 'Ven.', 'Sam.'],
            dayNamesMin: ['D', 'L', 'M', 'M', 'J', 'V', 'S'],
            weekHeader: 'Sem.',
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            firstDay: 1,

            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true,

            onSelect: function(date,obj){               
                var daty = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                console.log(daty);
                startDate = new Date(daty.getFullYear(), daty.getMonth(), daty.getDate() - daty.getDay());
                endDate = new Date(daty.getFullYear(), daty.getMonth(), daty.getDate() - daty.getDay() + 6);               
                var dateFormat = obj.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat;
                $('#startDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, startDate, obj.settings ));
                $('#endDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, endDate, obj.settings ));
                selectCurrentWeek();
                date = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', daty);
                console.log(date);
                $('#date_input').val(date);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thank you

Comment: see http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this  :

```
dateFormat: 'dd-MMMM',
```

Answer (score 0):

A good library for date format is

http://momentjs.com

From the documentation

```
 moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // August 13th 2017, 8:26:44
```